# Java paints graphics under the window boundaries

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to write a simple Java Applet/Application that will resize itself depending on how big it is. I have it basically working except when I paint something to the JFrame grpahics (jframe.getGraphics()), at the point 0,0, it seems to start at the upper left hand corner outside the boundaries of the window. having the first 30 or so pixels under the top bar of the window. Also jframe.getWidth() and jframe.getHeight() return to me the width and height of the window, not the visible part inside the window.

This is an excerpt of the code that I am using that demonstrates my problem:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class ImageHandler {
    private boolean debug;
    private int rememberWidth, rememberHeight, contractedImageX,
            contractedImageY, imageTranslationX, imageTranslationY, realWidth,
            realHeight, fixedWidth, fixedHeight;
    private BufferedImage bImage1, bImage2;
    private Graphics2D bufferedGraphics1, bufferedGraphics2;
    private boolean resizeNext, isApplet;

    public ImageHandler(ObjectHandler objH) {
        debug = objH.isDebug();
        objH.setImageHandler(this);
        objectHandler = objH;
        isApplet = objectHandler.isApplet();
        fixedWidth = objectHandler.getScreenWidth();
        fixedHeight = objectHandler.getScreenHeight();
    }

    public void paint(Paintable p) {
        /*
         * If the screen is not the same size at remembered, then re-run the
         * image transformations
         */
        realWidth = getRealWidth();
        realHeight = getRealHeight();
        if (objectHandler.isFocused() == true
                || objectHandler.isApplet() == true) {
            if (!(rememberWidth == realWidth && rememberHeight == realHeight)
                    || resizeNext) {
                resizeNext = false;
                if (debug)
                    System.out.println("Re-sizing");
                /* Create New Images */
                bImage1 = new BufferedImage(realWidth, realHeight,
                        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                bImage2 = new BufferedImage(fixedWidth, fixedHeight,
                        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                bufferedGraphics1 = (Graphics2D) bImage1.getGraphics();
                bufferedGraphics1.setColor(Color.black);
                bufferedGraphics1.fillRect(0, 0, realWidth, realHeight);
                bufferedGraphics2 = (Graphics2D) bImage2.getGraphics();
                /*
                 * Remember The current Height and width, so that it can check
                 * if the height has changed before running this again
                 */
                rememberWidth = realWidth;
                rememberHeight = realHeight;
                /*
                 * Define contractedImageX and y depending on the height of the
                 * screen
                 */
                contractedImageY = realHeight;
                contractedImageX = (int) ((double) contractedImageY
                        / (double) fixedHeight * fixedWidth);
                /*
                 * If the graphics defined by using the height make it go off
                 * the sides of the screen, redefine with the width
                 */
                if (debug) {
                    System.out.println("1Real Height:" + realHeight + " Width:"
                            + realWidth + " contractedHeight:"
                            + contractedImageY + " contractedWidth:"
                            + contractedImageX);
                }
                if (contractedImageX > realWidth) {
                    contractedImageX = realWidth;
                    contractedImageY = (int) ((double) contractedImageX
                            / (double) fixedWidth * fixedHeight);
                }
                if (debug) {
                    System.out.println("2Real Height:" + realHeight + " Width:"
                            + realWidth + " contractedHeight:"
                            + contractedImageY + " contractedWidth:"
                            + contractedImageX);
                }
                /*
                 * Re Calculate Image Translations so that they position the
                 * image correctly
                 */
                imageTranslationX = (realWidth - contractedImageX) / 2;
                imageTranslationY = (realHeight - contractedImageY) / 2;
                if (debug) {
                    System.out.println("X: " + imageTranslationX + " Y: "
                            + imageTranslationY);
                }

            }
            // clears the screen
            bufferedGraphics2.setColor(Color.black);
            bufferedGraphics2.fillRect(0, 0, fixedWidth, fixedHeight);
            p.paint(bufferedGraphics2);
            bufferedGraphics1.setColor(Color.black);
            bufferedGraphics1.fillRect(0, 0, realWidth, realHeight);
            bufferedGraphics1.drawImage(bImage2, imageTranslationX,
                    imageTranslationY, contractedImageX + imageTranslationX,
                    contractedImageY + imageTranslationY, 0, 0, fixedWidth,
                    fixedHeight, null);
            drawFinalImage(bImage1);
        }
    }

    private void drawFinalImage(Image img) {
        if (isApplet) {
            if (objectHandler.getjApplet() != null) {
                objectHandler.getjApplet().getGraphics()
                        .drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
            }
        } else {
            if (objectHandler.getjFrame() != null) {
                objectHandler.getjFrame().getGraphics()
                        .drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
            }
        }
    }

    private int getRealWidth() {
        if (objectHandler.isApplet()) {
            if (objectHandler.getjApplet() != null) {
                Integer w = objectHandler.getjApplet().getWidth();
                if (w != null && w > 0) {
                    return w;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (objectHandler.getjFrame() != null) {
                Integer w = objectHandler.getjFrame().getWidth();
                if (w != null && w > 0) {
                    return w;
                }
            }
        }
        return fixedWidth;
    }

    private int getRealHeight() {
        if (objectHandler.isApplet()) {
            if (objectHandler.getjApplet() != null) {
                Integer h = objectHandler.getjApplet().getHeight();
                if (h != null && h > 0) {
                    return h;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (objectHandler.getjFrame() != null) {
                Integer h = objectHandler.getjFrame().getHeight();
                if (h != null && h > 0) {
                    return h;
                }
            }
        }
        return fixedHeight;
    }
}
```

That code isn't my entire program, just the part that re sizes the window and paints the graphics.
Paintable is an interface I created that has the method paint(Graphcis g).

I am looking for a way to find what the width and height of the visible section is, and the
offset I need to find the point at the upper left hand corner of the visible section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add a custom JPanel and override getPreferredSize, as a JFrame takes decorations (title bar, etc.) into account.

```
private class MyPan extends JPanel {
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() { return new Dimension(600, 600); }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { /* do stuff */ }
}
```

Then just add the panel to the frame and pack(); the frame.

Comment: Thank you! This works! I didn't do this exactly, but a JPanel did what I needed doing, thank you!